# How to create file descriptors in loop and subsequently write into it

Tags: python, file-io

A similar question has been asked on [Python Multiple file writing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351007/python-multiple-file-writing-question), but it does not solve my case as the file descriptor is unique and I do not know how to create file descriptors dynamically in loop.

I have a huge file in the format given below:

```
field1  field2  field3  field4  field5
a   _   b   _   c
d   e   f   g   g
l   _   _   m   _
_   n   o   _   p
```

I need to create 5 separate files 'field1.txt', 'field2.txt',       'field3.txt',       'field4.txt' and       'field5.txt'.

I want to read the input file only once. For each line I am checking that if a field is not blank ('_') then write the complete line into the file that starts with the corresponding field name.

For example, since first, third and fifth fields of line 1 is not blank, this line will be written into file  'field1.txt', 'field3.txt' and       'field5.txt'.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Talking about "file descriptors" just makes your question confusing to read for people who know what file descriptors _are._ If you want file objects ask for file objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this comes to mind:

```
# TESTED
f = open('inputfile.txt')
line1 = next(f)
line1 = line1.split()
output_files = [open(fname+'.txt', 'w') for fname in line1]

for line in f:
  for output_file, field in zip(output_files, line.split()):
    if field != '_':
      output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Your solution is awesome. Also to add, there is resource limit on number of files that can be opened. By default it is 256 which can be increased by using "resource.setrlimit()" function.